# Angle between a vector and a subspace - is it the same between that vector and all the vectors in the subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u$ be a vector and $V$ be a finite dimensional real inner product space. We already know that angle between $u$ and $V$, $\theta$, is given by the angle between $u$ and $u$'s orthogonal projection onto $V$.

My question is: is that angle $\theta$ between the vector $u$ and the subspace $V$, also the angle between the vector $u$ and any vector $v\in V$?

Comment: No, in some sense it's the minimum of the angles between $u$ and vectors in $V$.

Comment: Indeed, if the angle between $u$ and the projection of $u$ onto $V$ has angle $\theta$, then the angle between $u$ and the negative of this projection is $\pi - \theta$.

Comment: If it is the minimum of the angles, does that mean that if I think of the basis vectors for that subspace, one of them will have the angle $\theta$ with the vector $u$, and that will be the minimum of all the angles of the basis vectors of the subspace with $u$?

Comment: No, basis is not unique. But, there can be a basis such that the angle is indeed equal to the angle between one of the basis elements and $u$. Make pictures in $\mathbb R^3$ to get the idea..

Comment: Thanks! How about an orthonormal basis? Or is there no simple way of finding the basis that this would hold for?

Comment: There is a simple way of finding the basis. You take the projection of $u$ onto $V$, call it $w$ and extend $\{w\}$ to a basis of $V$. You know that the angle between $u$ and $V$ is actually the angle between $u$ and $w$ and $w$ is in the basis of $V$.

Comment: @user135988 And then if I use an orthonormal basis so that all the other basis vectors are orthogonal to $w$, then the angle $\theta$ between $u$ and $w$ is the only non-orthogonal angle between $u$ and the rest of the basis for $V$! Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take for example the vector $u=(1,1,0)$ and the plane $V:y=0$. The angle between $u$ and $V$ is clearly $45$ deg but the vector $(0,0,1)$ is perpendicular to $u$.